# Android draw/add graphical border around a view

Tags: android, graphics, border

I'm not sure if I have the correct query and that's why I can't seem to find anything on this topic, but I am trying to add a graphical border to a view, let's say `textView` or `button` or even a `progressBar`.

To my knowledge you're supposed to take a texture or a small piece of the overall border and then draw it onto or near the view so you don't have to save 100 different sizes of the image (is this correct)? [image: Borders & Edges]

It's a pretty simple border, so I might be able to get away with just drawing it with colors (which I know how to do), but I would like to know how I would apply a texture like this to a view.

Any help is appreciated - even a related query/tutorial that I can go follow!